# How can I get preventDefault to work for all browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have weird problem with event.preventDefault. This works fine on Chrome but doesn't work on Firefox. I know many people fix it by adding event arg like this: myFunction(event) but doing this makes it stop working on both Chrome and Firefox. Can someone help me get this code working on all browsers?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction()
        {
                    var asdf = $('input[name=payment_type]:checked', '#buy').val()
                    if (asdf == 'theRightOne') {
                        event.preventDefault()      
                   alert("stuff")
                    } 
        }
      </script>
```

Comment: You might want to tag this as javascript -- you have tagged it for java, which is a different language environment entirely.

Comment: @arcy You know you've got enough reputation to retag a question, right?

Comment: Pls add the corresponding html

Comment: @Arkanon - thanks for the info, no I didn't know that.  Never occurred to me to look.  Never occurred to me to change someone else's post.  Need to learn a little more about (the rest of) SO, I guess.

Comment: @alib_15 <html>
<body>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction(event)
        {
                    var asdf = document.getElementById("lalala").value;
                    if (asdf == 'theRightOne') {
                        event.preventDefault()      
                   alert("stuff")
                    } 
        }
      </script>
   
<form method="post" name="form" action="actions2.php">
<input type="submit" value="theRightOne" id="lalala" name="paypal" onClick="myFunction()" />
</form>

</body>
</html>

Comment: @user3757605 Please edit your own question to update it with additional information. Adding detailed information as a comment makes it very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

Not all browsers are W3C-compliant, so they sometimes treat events in different ways. The following should work in most browsers:

```js
function eventHandler(e) {
  console.log('click event:', e);

  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    e.returnValue = false;
  }
}

function formSubmitDefault(e) {
  console.log('form submit event:', e);
}

document.getElementById('input').onclick = eventHandler;
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', formSubmitDefault);
```

```html
<form action="#" id="form">
  <input id="input" type="submit">
</form>
```

Here is a helpful [tutorial](http://javascript.info/tutorial/default-browser-action).

Comment: What aspect of it is not working? Btw, `preventDefault` should immediately stop execution of even the current handler, so the `alert('stuff')` may not execute if it's after the `preventDefault` call. Not sure if that's your issue . . .

Comment: It opens actions2.php

Comment: Have you tried assigning the `onclick` handler programatically as follows: `document.getElementById('lalala').onclick = myFunction;`? I'm not 100% sure but I think your problem may have to do with the `event` parameter of your function not being in scope when you assign the onclick handler inline in an HTML attribute.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it this way a while ago.